# how to call function inside a trigger?

Tags: sql-server

what is the problem with the @temp variable?

```
create function dbo.getNumOfReviews2 (@email varchar(40))
returns int
as begin
declare @numOfReviews int
    select @numOfReviews =  count(*)
    from dbo.Reviews
    where email = @email
    group by Email
return @numOfReviews 
end

CREATE TRIGGER setDiscount
ON dbo.[Contains]
FOR INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @OrderID int
    DECLARE @ProductID int
    DECLARE @Size VarChar(15)
    DECLARE @temp int
    IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','C_CURSOR')>=-1
        BEGIN
         DEALLOCATE C_CURSOR
        END
    DECLARE C_CURSOR CURSOR
    FOR SELECT ProductID,OrderID,Size
    FROM INSERTED
    BEGIN
        OPEN C_CURSOR
        FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @ProductID,@OrderID,@Size
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
            BEGIN
                @temp =  dbo.getNumOfReviews2(select BillingEmail from dbo.Orders where OrderID=@OrderID)
                IF (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM dbo.[Contains]
                    WHERE OrderID = @OrderID) > 5 or (SELECT sum(Quantity) FROM dbo.[Contains] WHERE OrderID=@OrderID) > 10 or
                    ( @temp )> 5
                        UPDATE [Contains]
                        SET [Savings%] = [Savings%] + 0.05
                        WHERE OrderID = @OrderID and ProductID = @ProductID and Size = @Size
                FETCH NEXT FROM C_CURSOR INTO @ProductID,@OrderID,@Size
            END

    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` to call scalar function

correct way to do this would be

```
select @temp = dbo.getNumOfReviews2(BillingEmail) 
from dbo.Orders 
where OrderID=@OrderID
```

**Note:** It is not advisable to write big logic inside a trigger. Triggers should be simple and fast otherwise your DML operations will be slow. Moreover you have used a `CURSOR` which should be avoided at any cost. Rewrite the code using SET based approach.

Here is a **SET based approach** code

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT c1.orderid 
         FROM   dbo.[contains] c1 
                INNER JOIN inserted i1 
                        ON i1.orderid = c1.orderid 
         GROUP  BY orderid 
         HAVING Count(*) > 5 
                 OR Sum(quantity) > 5 
                 OR @temp > 5) 
UPDATE C 
SET    [savings%] = [savings%] + 0.05 
FROM   [contains] C 
       INNER JOIN inserted I 
               ON I.orderid = C.orderid 
                  AND I.productid = C.productid 
                  AND I.size = C.size 
                  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM   cte c1 
                              WHERE  c1.orderid = c.orderid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE COVID19VMS_VACCINESHOT_T1

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON VACCINENEXTSHOTDATE 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

IF :NEW.VACCINESHOTDATE := 1

:NEW.VACCINEXTSHOTDATE := to_date(VACCINESHOTDATE +28)

END IF; 

IF :NEW.VACCINESHOTDATE :=2

:NEW.VACCINENEXTSHOTDATE IS NULL

END IF

END
```

Comment: IF UNDER 100 SET VACCINENEXTSHOTDATE = NULL